# How to display spinner selected value in another/next activity as spinner itself in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a spinner named as "product name" in my app. When I select the product's nam" from my spinner, the value is selected.

Now, what I need is the same spinner with the selected value to be displayed in another activity. How can I do that?

**Product Name:
Mobile Handset**

Imagine `Mobile Handset` as my selected spinner item and product name is a text view. I want the same as it is in above spinner in my next activity.

Comment: i can do it with spinner itself..i mean it should be displayed as spinner selected value in next activity..if you could give me a example it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is get the selected item **index** from the spinner like this:

```
int index = yourSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition(); //Basically you get the index of your item
```

Then you pass it through a `Bundle`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourAnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("SPINNER_ITEM", index);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your another activity, on its `onCreate()` method do this:

```
int selectedItemIndex = getIntent().getIntExtra("SPINNER_ITEM", 0);
yourSpinnerInAnotherActivity.setSelection(selectedItemIndex);
```

You should store the `SPINNER_ITEM` as a string resource to avoid typos. Also, this will only work if you already have the same items in the another spinner in another activity.

Comment: thanks @gaurav mall,and i dont have any spinner in my another activity ..i just need to place the same spinner with selected value in next activity..so will the above method work?

Comment: well, you need to create another spinner in the other activity. Sadly, there is no way to copy elements to other activities. this method works if you have another spinner with the same values as the first one, in your second activity.

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions. Please also see: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)